# ConversionNotSupportedException problem in Spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

There are lots of exception error i dont know why. But to my mind it is about xml or application properties file. Also it is springBoot Project. I want to connect database postgreSQL. Btw this will be rentACar application

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>FirstSpringBootProject</groupId>
   <artifactId>RentACar</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>RentACar</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
         <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>2.7.5</version>
      </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>
                     <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                  </exclude>
               </excludes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

My BrandService Interface

```
package FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.business.abstracts;

import FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.entities.concretes.Brand;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
@Service
public interface BrandService {

    List<Brand> getAll();

}
```

My BrandManager class

```
package FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.business.concretes;

import FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.business.abstracts.BrandService;

import FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.dataAccess.abstracts.BrandRepository;
import FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.entities.concretes.Brand;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
@Service
public class BrandManager implements BrandService {

    BrandRepository brandRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BrandManager(BrandRepository brandRepository) {
        this.brandRepository = brandRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public List<Brand> getAll() {
        return brandRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

BrandRepository

```
package FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.dataAccess.abstracts;

import FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.entities.concretes.Brand;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;



public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand,Integer> {

}
```

Brand Entity class

```
package FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.entities.concretes;

import lombok.*;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name = "Brand")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Brand {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;


}
```

and so controller

```
package FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.webApi.Controller;

import FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.business.abstracts.BrandService;


import FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.entities.concretes.Brand;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/brands")
public class BrandsController {
    BrandService brandService;

    @Autowired
    public BrandsController(BrandService brandService) {
        this.brandService = brandService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getall")
    public List<Brand> getAll()
    {
        return brandService.getAll();
    }

}
```

Application Properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode = none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/RentACarCamp1
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Error is like that

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'brandManager' defined in file [C:\Users\User\Desktop\rentACar\target\classes\FirstSpringBootProject\RentACar\business\concretes\BrandManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'brandRepository' defined in FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.dataAccess.abstracts.BrandRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy89 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy89 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:242) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.RentACarApplication.main(RentACarApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brandRepository' defined in FirstSpringBootProject.RentACar.dataAccess.abstracts.BrandRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy89 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy89 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:606) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy89 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy89 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:594) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:608) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:190) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1711) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1668) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy89 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:589) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 38 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

i Get some code from stackOverflow but nothing i found in a week(

Comment: can you please share error stacktrace?

Comment: yeah sorry,I have shared.@RohitAgarwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the root cause of the issue. The issue is coming because of the below dependencies present in the `pom.xml` file.

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>

       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>2.7.5</version>
      </dependency>
```

Please remove these dependencies and try again.

**Note** - This JPA dependency is enough for database connectivity.

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: i did  them,But the problem haven't solved( Can you help me in another way?

Comment: Is your problem solved or not? If not then what error coming now?

Comment: i Have founded another solution,thanks)